# scrappig an HTML tag on the web page using BS

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

Image description is:

[image]

Tag is:

[image]

I was looking to get the data in the stock dropdown. I went into the source and found the tag but I can't get the code to access the data. Can someone please help me fix the bug?

```
url ="http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/fnoquote/reliance-industries/RI/2020-07-30"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for i in soup.select("stock_id"):
     print(i.text)
```

Comment: Perhaps `soup.select("#stock_code")` as I cannot see `stock_id` in the image you linked to. Note also the hash mark (#)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#stock_code > option` instead of `stock_id` to get the data in the stock dropdown.You can try it:

```
url ="http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/fnoquote/reliance-industries/RI/2020-07-30"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'}

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
a  = soup.select("#stock_code > option")

for i in a:
      print(i.text)
```

Output will be:

```
ACC
Adani Enterpris
Adani Ports
Adani Power
Ajanta Pharma
Allahabad Bank
Amara Raja Batt
Ambuja Cements
Apollo Hospital
Apollo Tyres
Arvind
Ashok Leyland
Asian Paints
Aurobindo Pharm
Axis Bank
Bajaj Auto
Bajaj Finance
Bajaj Finserv
Balkrishna Ind
Bank of Baroda
Bank of India
Bata India
BEML
Berger Paints
Bharat Elec
Bharat Fin
Bharat Forge
Bharti Airtel
Bharti Infratel
BHEL
Biocon
Bosch
BPCL
Britannia
Cadila Health
Can Fin Homes
Canara Bank
Capital First
Castrol
Ceat
Century
CESC
CG Power 
Chennai Petro
Cholamandalam
Cipla
Coal India
Colgate
Container Corp
Cummins
Dabur India
Dalmia Bharat
DCB Bank
Dewan Housing
Dish TV
Divis Labs
DLF
Dr Reddys Labs
Eicher Motors
EngineersInd
Equitas Holding
Escorts
Exide Ind
Federal Bank
GAIL
Glenmark
GMR Infra
Godfrey Phillip
Godrej Consumer
Godrej Ind
Granules India
Grasim
GSFC
Havells India
HCL Tech
HDFC
HDFC Bank
Hero Motocorp
Hexaware Tech
Hind Constr
Hind Zinc
Hindalco
HPCL
HUL
ICICI Bank
ICICI Prudentia
IDBI Bank
IDFC
IDFC Bank
IFCI
IGL
India Cements
Indiabulls Hsg
Indian Bank
IndusInd Bank
Infibeam Avenue
Infosys
Interglobe Avi
IOC
IRB Infra
ITC
Jain Irrigation
Jaiprakash Asso
Jet Airways
Jindal Steel
JSW Steel
Jubilant Food
Just Dial
Kajaria Ceramic
Karnataka Bank
Kaveri Seed
Kotak Mahindra
KPIT Tech
L&T Finance
Larsen
LIC Housing Fin
Lupin
M&M
M&M Financial
Mahanagar Gas
Manappuram Fin
Marico
Maruti Suzuki
Max Financial
MCX India
Mindtree
Motherson Sumi
MRF
MRPL
Muthoot Finance
NALCO
NBCC (India)
NCC
Nestle
NHPC
NIIT Tech
NMDC
NTPC
Oil India
ONGC
Oracle Fin Serv
Oriental Bank
Page Industries
PC Jeweller
Petronet LNG
Pidilite Ind
Piramal Enter
PNB
Power Finance
Power Grid Corp
PTC India
PVR
Ramco Cements
Raymond
RBL Bank
REC
Rel Capital
Reliance
Reliance Comm
Reliance Infra
Reliance Power
Repco Home
SAIL
SBI
Shree Cements
Shriram Trans
Siemens
South Ind Bk
SREI Infra
SRF
Strides Pharma 
Sun Pharma
Sun TV Network
Suzlon Energy
Syndicate Bank
Tata Chemicals
Tata Comm
Tata Elxsi
Tata Global Bev
Tata Motors
Tata Motors (D)
Tata Power
Tata Steel
TCS
Tech Mahindra
Titan Company
Torrent Pharma
Torrent Power
TV18 Broadcast
TVS Motor
Ujjivan Financi
UltraTechCement
Union Bank
United Brewerie
United Spirits
UPL
V-Guard Ind
Vedanta
Vodafone Idea
Voltas
Wipro
Wockhardt
Yes Bank
Zee Entertain
Select
ACC
Adani Enterpris
Adani Ports
Adani Power
Ajanta Pharma
Allahabad Bank
Amara Raja Batt
Ambuja Cements
Apollo Hospital
Apollo Tyres
Arvind
Ashok Leyland
Asian Paints
Aurobindo Pharm
Axis Bank
Bajaj Auto
Bajaj Finance
Bajaj Finserv
Balkrishna Ind
Bank of Baroda
Bank of India
Bata India
BEML
Berger Paints
Bharat Elec
Bharat Fin
Bharat Forge
Bharti Airtel
Bharti Infratel
BHEL
Biocon
Bosch
BPCL
Britannia
Cadila Health
Can Fin Homes
Canara Bank
Capital First
Castrol
Ceat
Century
CESC
CG Power 
Chennai Petro
Cholamandalam
Cipla
Coal India
Colgate
Container Corp
Cummins
Dabur India
Dalmia Bharat
DCB Bank
Dewan Housing
Dish TV
Divis Labs
DLF
Dr Reddys Labs
Eicher Motors
EngineersInd
Equitas Holding
Escorts
Exide Ind
Federal Bank
GAIL
Glenmark
GMR Infra
Godfrey Phillip
Godrej Consumer
Godrej Ind
Granules India
Grasim
GSFC
Havells India
HCL Tech
HDFC
HDFC Bank
Hero Motocorp
Hexaware Tech
Hind Constr
Hind Zinc
Hindalco
HPCL
HUL
ICICI Bank
ICICI Prudentia
IDBI Bank
IDFC
IDFC Bank
IFCI
IGL
India Cements
Indiabulls Hsg
Indian Bank
IndusInd Bank
Infibeam Avenue
Infosys
Interglobe Avi
IOC
IRB Infra
ITC
Jain Irrigation
Jaiprakash Asso
Jet Airways
Jindal Steel
JSW Steel
Jubilant Food
Just Dial
Kajaria Ceramic
Karnataka Bank
Kaveri Seed
Kotak Mahindra
KPIT Tech
L&T Finance
Larsen
LIC Housing Fin
Lupin
M&M
M&M Financial
Mahanagar Gas
Manappuram Fin
Marico
Maruti Suzuki
Max Financial
MCX India
Mindtree
Motherson Sumi
MRF
MRPL
Muthoot Finance
NALCO
NBCC (India)
NCC
Nestle
NHPC
NIIT Tech
NMDC
NTPC
Oil India
ONGC
Oracle Fin Serv
Oriental Bank
Page Industries
PC Jeweller
Petronet LNG
Pidilite Ind
Piramal Enter
PNB
Power Finance
Power Grid Corp
PTC India
PVR
Ramco Cements
Raymond
RBL Bank
REC
Rel Capital
Reliance
Reliance Comm
Reliance Infra
Reliance Power
Repco Home
SAIL
SBI
Shree Cements
Shriram Trans
Siemens
South Ind Bk
SREI Infra
SRF
Strides Pharma 
Sun Pharma
Sun TV Network
Suzlon Energy
Syndicate Bank
Tata Chemicals
Tata Comm
Tata Elxsi
Tata Global Bev
Tata Motors
Tata Motors (D)
Tata Power
Tata Steel
TCS
Tech Mahindra
Titan Company
Torrent Pharma
Torrent Power
TV18 Broadcast
TVS Motor
Ujjivan Financi
UltraTechCement
Union Bank
United Brewerie
United Spirits
UPL
V-Guard Ind
Vedanta
Vodafone Idea
Voltas
Wipro
Wockhardt
Yes Bank
Zee Entertain
```